I want to create digital terrain model using lidar file python
I have a lidar image and I want to create a dtm image using python, but the methods I tried do not give the result I want.

I want a smooth look, but I sharpen the trees.
I have tried a few methods with the pdal library in Python, but in general the filters give errors or do not give the results I want. Can you help me with this? There may be a different method.
I tried this json file.,
{
  "pipeline":[
        "lasfile.las",
      {
          "type":"filters.reprojection",
          "in_srs":"EPSG:5255",
          "out_srs":"EPSG:5255"
      },
      {
        "type":"filters.assign",
        "assignment":"Classification[:]=0"
      },
      {
        "type":"filters.elm"
      },
      {
        "type":"filters.outlier"
      },
      {

        "type":"filters.smrf",
        "slope":0.005,
        "window":64,
        "threshold":10.0,
        "scalar":5.0
      },
      {
        "type": "writers.gdal",
        
        "filename":"dtm.tif",
        "output_type":"idw",
        "gdaldriver":"GTiff",
        "resolution": 0.5,
        "radius": 1
      },
      {
        "type":"filters.range",
        "limits":"Classification[2:2]"
      }
  ]
}````


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.
